# merging of two files in unix and looping the merged files

Tags: unix, curl

I have two files where,where each file has 240 curl commands, I want to merge these two file1 and file2 to file3.
Also, i want run this merged file in a loop starting from one 1st curl command to 480th curl command.

Pls help

Answer (score 0):

Create file3:

```
touch file3
```

copy over the data

```
cat file1 >> file3
cat file2 >> file3
```

run the file

```
source file3
```

Comment: i want to merge one line from file and next line should be from file2. Does cat server this purpose? or it just append file2 to the end of file1?

Comment: No it does not. This was not mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to merge one line from file and next line should be from file2.

```
paste -d'\n' file1 file2 >file3
```